# cron cannot read outside of account folder

Tags: permissions, cron, symlink

I have a folder on my websites calld /administrator/cron - in it I place php files and then in the cron tab I have something like:

```
* * * * * php -f "/home/cpm394/public_html/administrator/cron/mailqueue.php"
```

which USED TO WORK a few months ago.

(BTW this is on a dedicated Linux server with Hostgator)

in the website I have some symbolic links as follows:

```
ln -s /home/phplib/public_html/functions functions
```

SO... here's the problem:

the script in mailqueue.php requires a file as follows:

```
require('/home/cpm394/public_html/functions/config.php');
```

In response, I get a message that the file does not exist (and it does, I have checked it).

Is this a permission problem?  I would normally expect to get "permission denied" vs. "file does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs are often sensitive to relative paths. If you are using them anywhere, try using the full absolute paths instead.